# Update table with While loop reading id first

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, sql-update

I just wanted to ask something, I want to update a table, but this table 300k rows, it is taking about 1.8 - 2.3 seconds per row this is the table I need to update, if name match with a column i need to set the value of column All, 
`ID  |cexp_cod   |All    |name   |New    |Normal |Vip
1   |13 |9  |Vip    |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
2   |16 |9  |Vip    |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
3   |16 |6  |Normal |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
4   |18 |9  |Vip    |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
5   |23 |9  |New    |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
6   |25 |9  |New    |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
7   |26 |9  |Vip    |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
8   |27 |9  |New    |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
9   |40 |9  |Vip    |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
10  |43 |9  |Vip    |NULL   |NULL   |NULL
11  |43 |6  |Normal |NULL   |NULL   |NULL`

and this is my query:

```
 DECLARE @loop      smallint     = 0
,@v_xp_cod      varchar(max) = 0
,@v_name            varchar(MAX) = NULL
,@v_pond        varchar(max) = 0
,@v_id              bigint       = 0

WHILE @loop = 0
    BEGIN

        SELECT TOP 1 @v_xp_cod = query01.xp_cod 
        ,@v_name = query01.name
        ,@v_pond = query01.All
        ,@v_id = query01.ID
        FROM (
            SELECT xp_cod 
            , name
            , All 
            , ID
            FROM temp WITH(NOLOCK)
        ) AS query01
        WHERE query01.ID > @v_id
        ORDER BY query01.ID ASC

        IF @@rowcount=0
        BEGIN
            SET @loop=1
        END

        ELSE -- update
        BEGIN

            DECLARE @i_update nvarchar(MAX)=null
            SELECT @i_update = 'UPDATE temp
                                SET [' +@v_name+ '] = '+@v_pond+'
                                WHERE xp_cod = ' + @v_xp_cod 
            EXECUTE sp_executesql  @i_update

        END         
    END
```

Comment: Why are you updating your table 1 column at a time with a loop? Why not just use a normal update statement? Also, why the NOLOCK hint? Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate data?

Comment: I do because because the columns on this table where created dynamically based on the data of the column name, what i basically want is to send the value from the column ALL to the column in which it match, i am do in it this way because it could be a random name of column

Comment: Ugh ultimate flexibility and ultimate performance issue. You should look at using FOR XML to generate your dynamic update statement. It is still not great but it would certainly be better than 1 column at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try rewriting the query using a different approach or format:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumnName =
( SELECT table2.Name
 FROM table2
 WHERE table2.my_id = MyTable.id)
WHERE EXISTS
   ( SELECT table2.Name
     FROM table2
     WHERE table2.my_id = MyTable.id);
```

Comment: I am doing it that way because the name of the column in the table is unknown, it was created dynamically based on the column NAME, so what i am trying to do is to send the value of column NAME in the one who matches on the table